# WebRTC: Any sample for "degrade a call and turn video off"?

Tags: webrtc

### Description

The sample [upgrade a call and turn video on](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/upgrade/) is very intuitive. However, is there any reverse sample of "degrade a call and turn video off"?

### Scenario

We are going to implement a toggle of a bi-directional audio/video call. At the beginning, the call is only for audio. After we click "upgrade to video call", then the bi-directional video tracks are added. Then we click "downgrade to audio call", it recovers to the audio call as the one in the beginning. Note that the video/audio toggle should be done in unlimited times.

### Investigation

I think I should invoke "removeTrack" from the caller and start to renegotiate. But on the callee side, how could we remove the video track from the H5 video player?

Comment: When I call `removeTrack()` and then call `createOffer()`, there is an error message: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setLocalDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set local offer sdp: The order of m-lines in subsequent offer doesn't match order from previous offer/answer.`.

Comment: Maybe I could mute on both side. However, is there any better solution?

Comment: When I call `removeTrack()`, it will trigger re-negotiation. That is good. No need to call `createOffer`. But on the callee side, still no clue.

Comment: On the remote side, just call `removeTrack()` and send answer. It works. However, we can't add audio track again, it complains `Failed to set remote offer sdp: The order of m-lines in subsequent offer doesn't match order from previous offer/answer.`.

Comment: I find that we can't keep adding/removing tracks. Since `removeTrack()` won't remove sender, the offer will contain more and more `m=audio` items which eventually leads to `Failed to set remote offer sdp: The order of m-lines in subsequent offer doesn't match order from previous offer/answer`.

Comment: I get it work by using `replaceTrack()`. But the solution is imperfect. We have to call `addTrack()` and trigger renegotiation at the first time. After that, we can call `replaceTrack(null)` to disable audio or call `replaceTrack(audio)` to enable audio. The code is messy. A better solution could be adding a dummy transceiver at the beginning. Then no renegotiation is necessary. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find a solution. The bi-directional dummy audio tracks are added in the beginning. Then we can call `replaceTrack()` of the transceiver to switch audio. No re-negotiation is necessary.

Thanks [this blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/warm-up-with-replacetrack/), I can't do it without this blog. And [this blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/rtcrtptransceiver-explored/) is also helpful.

But the solution is still imperfect. A dummy audio track is still created for both sides, which means a little bit network traffic is wasted. A perfect solution should shun down the transmission when there is no real audio track.